# 'then is not a function' in MongoDB Stitch Webhook

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

The [MongoDB Stitch Webhook docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/http/) describe my precise use case: using a `POST` method to call `insertOne` then return the inserted _id.

I pasted the example below (directly from the docs) into the Stitch Function Editor.

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const requestLogs = mongodb.db("test").collection("requestlogs");
  requestLogs.insertOne({
    body: EJSON.parse(payload.body.text()),
    query: payload.query
  }).then(result => {
    response.setStatusCode(201);
    response.setBody(result.insertedId);
  })
};
```

I executed the function in the Function Editor console by calling:

```
exports({query: {arg1: 'hello', arg2: "world!"}, body:BSON.Binary.fromText('{"msg": "world"}')})
```

An error is returned indicating that `.then` is not a function.

> error: TypeError: **'then' is not a function**

Are the docs wrong, or I have I gone astray?

Comment: Have you tried `return requestLogs.insertOne(...)`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried that and the same TypeError was returned.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied your steps but was not able to reproduce the issue. When I use your exports in the Function Editor console, I do get an error with the fact that `response` is undefined, but I can work around this by mocking out the second parameter: `exports({query: {arg1: 'hello', arg2: "world!"}, body:BSON.Binary.fromText('{"msg": "world"}')}, {setStatusCode: () => {}, setBody: () => {}})`. If you are still having issues, you might also get answers on the [MongoDB community slack](https://launchpass.com/mongo-db) #stitch channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain methods, like `.then`, throw errors in the function editor. In my case, this was a shortcoming of the function editor, rather than an error in my code. **Calling the webhook with `fetch` or Postman, the function executed as expected.**

The [Incoming Webhook](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/create-a-service-webhook/) docs contain a special note:

> If you want to debug a webhook function response from the function
>   editor, you must manually provide the HTTP response object when you
>   run the function.
>
> **exports(   { body: "This document is the webhook payload" },   new
>   HTTPResponse() )**

That alerted me to the idiosyncratic nature of the function editor as a JS handler. Using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) I confirmed the function ran without errors when called. The error generated by the function editor was a red herring.